# Keyboard, mouse response very sluggish

Tags: windows, keyboard, performance, mouse, input-device

> Please describe the issue in 2-3 sentences. Include what you're trying to accomplish when the issue occurs.

Both the keyboard and mouse exhibit significant delay before input is registered on-screen. This occurs in all applications, at all times. CPU/RAM/SSD usage remains low.

> When did it begin and how often does it occur?

It began about two/three months ago, under my Windows 10 Pro installation. I'd hoped that this Windows 11 Pro clean install would address the problem, but alas it hasn't.

> What errors do you see?

No errors, just jerky response on-screen. It's as though keyboard & mouse inputs (to include the scroll wheel) are being buffered and then released once every half-second or so.

> What's the environment and are there recent changes?

Domain-joined Dell Inspiron 7737, 4th gen Intel i7, 16 GB RAM. Recent installation of Windows 11, but the problem was occurring under Windows 10 as well.

How can I troubleshoot this, in hopes of tracking down the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking like this was all a comedy of errors.

At the time I assessed the situation with Win11, it was a clean install with no third-party apps installed. Excepting a browser: Brave, a privacy-focused Chrome derivative.

I also didn't fully assess the environment before posting here (pardon me, please). Further investigation revealed that the lagging performance I was seeing under 11 was in Brave only. Other apps—Notepad, Wordpad, etc.—exhibited no such input lag.

I've since moved everything over to Edge (I truly will miss Brave with its superior privacy-enhancing armor) and all seems well. Even Visual Studio, the main offender previously, does quite well now.

As for what the problem was under Win10... well, that OS is long gone by now, so who knows. And for that matter, who cares? Not me.